# Image of a line bundle on an elliptic curve under Fourier-Mukai transform

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, derived-categories

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve with a base point $p$. What is the image of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_E(np)$ under the Fourier-Mukai transform with a kernel given by the Poincare bundle on $E\times E$?

Comment: What is your definition of the Poincare bundle?